# How to edit an existing index in Sequel Pro?

Tags: mysql, macos, sequelpro

Is there a way to edit an existing index in Sequel Pro (Mac OSX)? In the Indexes pane, I only see a plus (add) and minus (remove). I can't seem to modify any of the existing indexes, such as renaming it or adding more columns to create a multi-column (composite) index.

[image: Indexes pane in Sequel Pro]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to edit an existing index. [There exists a corresponding feature request in their bug tracker.](https://github.com/sequelpro/sequelpro/issues/889) One has to drop the index and create a new one.

Comment: I ended up using Valentina Studio and it's been great. Gives me the ability to edit compound indexes easily.